# Transform coordinate to whole circle's area OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, coordinates

I'm new to OpenLayers and currently have a project that used OpenLayers for displaying maps. When I click on any address in the map, one circle will be drawn based on the address (coordinate).

My question is after I click on the map, once the circle is drawn, if I click on any points inside the drawn circle, OpenLayers will just only return the `same coordinate` as it was at the first time.

I know my question is tedious but just curious and want to know is there any way or possible to achieve that.

[image]

Here is the code for drawing the circle and getting the coordinate. This code will generate different coordinate based on the point I click on the map no matter the point is inside or outside the drawn circle:

`css`

```
<style>
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
  }

  .map {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

`html`

```
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

`js`

```
<script>
  var map = new ol.Map({
    target: "map",
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM(),
      }),
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([126.5, 35]),
      zoom: 3,
    }),
  });

  var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    // NOTE: Provides a source of features for vector layers. Vector features provided by this source are suitable for editing
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
      projection: "EPSG:4326",
      //   projection: "EPSG:3857",

      features: [],
    }),
  });

  map.addLayer(layer);
  // handle map click
  map.on("click", handleMapClick);
  var vectorSource = layer.getSource();

  function createCircle(
    circleCenterX,
    circleCenterY,
    circleRadius,
    pointsToEnd
  ) {
    let angleToAdd = 360 / pointsToEnd;
    let coords = [];
    let angle = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < pointsToEnd; i++) {
      angle += angleToAdd;
      let coordX =
        circleCenterX + circleRadius * Math.cos((angle * Math.PI) / 180);
      let coordY =
        circleCenterY + circleRadius * Math.sin((angle * Math.PI) / 180);
      coords.push([coordX, coordY]);
    }
    return coords;
  }

  function addCircle(coords) {
    var circleCoords = createCircle(coords[0], coords[1], 2, 9);
    console.log("circle coordinates", circleCoords);

    var polygon = new ol.geom.Polygon([circleCoords]);
    console.log(`polygon: ${JSON.stringify(polygon)}`);
    polygon.transform("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857");

    polygon = new ol.Feature(polygon);
    vectorSource.addFeature(polygon);
  }

  function handleMapClick(evt) {

    addCircle(
      ol.proj.transform(evt.coordinate, "EPSG:900913", "EPSG:4326")
    );
    
    console.log(
      `transformed coordinate: ${ol.proj.transform(
        evt.coordinate,
        "EPSG:900913",
        "EPSG:4326"
      )}`
    );
  }
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, when you click on existing circle, you don't want to create a new circle, just get the center coordinates of the clicked circle?

Comment: @TomazicM yeah, that is that I mean!

Answer (score 1):

When processing map click with `handleMapClick` function, you can use map's `forEachFeatureAtPixel` method to check if click was on existing circle feature. To get circle/feature center coordinate, the simplest way is to add it as custom property (let's say `centerCoords`) to the feature at the time of creation.

Relevant part of the code could then look something like this:

```
function addCircle(coords) {
  var circleCoords = createCircle(coords[0], coords[1], 2, 9);

  var polygon = new ol.geom.Polygon([circleCoords]);
  polygon.transform("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857");

  polygon = new ol.Feature(polygon);
  polygon.set('centerCoords', coords);
  vectorSource.addFeature(polygon);
}

function handleMapClick(evt) {
  var found = false;
  map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
    console.log('Existing circle center', feature.get('centerCoords'));
    found = true;
  });
  if (found) return;

  addCircle(
    ol.proj.transform(evt.coordinate, "EPSG:900913", "EPSG:4326")
  );
  console.log(
    `transformed coordinate: ${ol.proj.transform(
      evt.coordinate,
      "EPSG:900913",
      "EPSG:4326"
    )}`
  );
}
```